# Postgresql very slow convert from row to json string, despite fast subquery

Tags: postgresql

I want to return table as json.

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) from (select * from fastSubquery)t
```

Subquery runs around 400-500ms, but wrapped in this json wrapper total time is 5 sec.

Is there a better approach less time consuming?

UPD: json_agg(t) shows similar result

Comment: So how many rows does your "fast subquery" return? Aggregating thousands of rows into one single gigantic JSON value is going to be costly.

Comment: Well yes, It looks like so. I have about 3000-5000 rows.